# Trying to create a random number generator using Arrays and getting Identifier "i" is Undefined. Can anyone see the problem?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, undefined, identifier

Trying to create a random number generator using Arrays, but the " **a[i] = rand()**;" portion of my code creates an error of the type "**Identifier i is Undefined**". Can anyone find where I am going wrong here? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int a[10] = {};  
  
   
    for (int i = 0; i < size(a); i++); {

        a[i] = rand();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size(a); i++) {

        cout << "The random number is: " << a[i] << endl;

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:15:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        a[i] = rand();
          ^
main.cpp:13:38: warning: for loop has empty body
      [-Wempty-body]
    for (int i = 0; i < size(a); i++); {
                                     ^
main.cpp:13:38: note: put the semicolon on a separate line
      to silence this warning
1 warning and 1 error generated.
compiler exit status 1
```

clang helpfully notes that you have an unexpected semicolon after your  for loop.

Comment: Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code was a stray semicolon. Try learning debuggers like gdb, will help for such problems. `rand()` function uses a seed, `srand()` is used to change/set the seed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>. // Added for random seed generation

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int a[10] = {};  
  
    srand(time(0)); /* Added this to ensure seed of rand() is always different otherwise you might have ended up with same random numbers on different runs */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size(a); i++) {   /*Issue was here, you had stray semicolon */

        a[i] = rand();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size(a); i++) {

        cout << "The random number is: " << a[i] << endl;

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. It works fine now.